# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer error

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I don't understand how the freeing is working. I know this happens when I try to free memory twice. However, this is really stumping me.

I've tried to post just the relevant parts of the code.

```
FILE* file = fopen(path, "r");
if (file == NULL)
{
    error(500);
    return;
}

// load file's content
BYTE* content;
size_t length;
if (load(file, &content, &length) == false)
{
    error(500);
    return;
}
```

This is the load fucntion

```
bool load(FILE* file, BYTE** content, size_t* length)
{
    printf("\nLOAD STARTED\n");
    content = NULL;
    BYTE *data = NULL;
    int size = 0;
    while(!feof(file))
    {
        char ch = fgetc(file);
        size += 1;
        data = realloc(data, sizeof(BYTE) * (size));
        *(data + (size - 1)) = ch;
    }
    content = &data;
    *length = size;
    printf("\nLOAD ENDED\n");
    return true;
}
```

A little while later I'm calling free()

```
printf("\nFREEING CONTENT\n");
// free file's content
free(content);
printf("\nCONTENT FREED\n");
```

The printf statement `FREEING CONTENT` works after which I get the

`munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer` error.

Comment: `content = &data;` -->> `*content = data;`

Comment: `data[size] = ch;` --> `data[size++] = ch;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY got the problem - you're never changing `size` so your `data` buffer never gets bigger.  Also, [`while(!feof(file))` is (almost always) wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) - and it *is* wrong in your code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yeah I noticed that about size. After fixing it, I still get a segmentation fault while freeing. There is something wrong in the memory allocation. Although printing out *data like a string has all the contents of the file.

Comment: You never check the `realloc` return value for `NULL`. Why do you expect it can't fail?

Comment: And `content = NULL;` at the beginning is dangerous bullshit. `*content = NULL;` could work, but is not necessary (since you still have `data = NULL;` at the beginning. And (intend to) do `*content = data;` at the end.)

Comment: @AbhishekManiyal *Although printing out *data like a string has all the contents of the file.*  Well, you do read and store the data, since`realloc()` does return a pointer to a zero-byte block of memory.  But `read()` overruns the end of that buffer and overwrites other memory.  This is a perfect example of "undefined behavior" in that it seems to work, but other problems happen later.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
content = &data;
```

It assigns the address of a local variable that goes out of scope after the function returns. Since content is a function parameter, nothing gets written to where it points. Did you mean to write

```
*content = data;
```

instead? If so you, you should not set `content = NULL` because you want to use the address passed by the call `load(file, &content, &length)`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. 
`content` was basically just a `char*`. So, I tried this and it worked...

I changed `content = &data` to `content = &(data[0])`

It works. Appreciate all the inputs. :D